# How to obtain Vim's command line?

Tags: command-line

I want to see what shell command line were used to start Vim. For example, I used command

```
vim -S Session.vim
```

`argv()` and `argc()` don't show switches and it's parameters.

Command

```
:echo tr(join(readfile("/proc/" . getpid() . "/cmdline")), "\n", " ")
```

shows command line. But, is there more elegant (shorter) method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the special `v:` variable [v:argv](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#argv-variable), which would show, when running `vim -S Session.vim` exactly this:

```
:echo v:argv
['vim', '-S', 'Session.vim']
```

In addition, to get the proper vim binary, you should probably also use the `v:progpath` variable, which specifies the exact path of the vim binary that was run (which matters if you have several vim binaries installed, because e.g. you compile your own version)

Comment: There is no `v:argv` in Vim 7.4 that I use. But thanks for hint.

Comment: yeah, it was added later in [v8.1.2233](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/69bf634858a2a75f2984e42b1e) You should really consider to upgrade, 7.4 is really old now

Comment: I like classic versions when I start use'n Vim. `:terminal`, VimL9...

Comment: I do to. But still you wouldn't get all the security updates and some of the core vim feature enhancements

Comment: I'm inspired [Your problem with Vim...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118). And Vim 7.4 never sum up me on 2 machines: Linux 2.6 and Cygwin. New features are OK. But for me 7.4 is enough.

Comment: you are still missing a whole lot of security patches

Comment: Vim is not browser or something like. It's simply text editor. What patches so need?

Comment: of course not. That doesn't mean there are not relevant security patches. I think this is obvious

Comment: What patches so need for prog with 20 years old (on 2013) and such community? I follow for changes. No bells rings.

Comment: See yourself (taken from Debian Changelog) and search for CVE: https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/v/vim/vim_8.2.2434-3+deb11u1_changelog